# How to listen to 3d cursor changes in Blender script?

Tags: scripting

I'd like to create script that does something to the scene every time 3d cursor moves. So far all handlers I've checked fire only when some object on scene changes, except 3d cursor. If possible I'd like to avoid polling for it every second. My question is whether there is handler in Blender that fires every time 3d cursor location is changed.

Answer (score 5):

#### Message Bus (bpy.msgbus)

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html

```
import bpy

def msgbus_callback():
    print("3D cursor location change to: ", bpy.context.scene.cursor.location)

owner = (bpy.types.View3DCursor, "location")

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=owner,
    owner=owner,
    args=(),
    notify=msgbus_callback,
)
```

##### Since in some cases using Message Bus doesn't work, it is proposed to use Application Handlers (bpy.app.handlers)

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

last_loc = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location.copy()

@persistent
def on_depsgraph_update(dummy):
    if bpy.context.scene.cursor.location != last_loc:
        loc = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
        print("3D cursor location change to: ", loc)
        last_loc[:] = loc

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(on_depsgraph_update)
```

Comment: Note that as per the documentation this will not work for changes directly in the 3D viewport (SHIFT + right click, SHIFT + S > Cursor to selected, etc)

Comment: Wow, thank you. Application Handlers do seem to work with SHIFT+right click

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ it no longer works as of Blender 3.5.1

Comment: I recently tested on 3.6 and it still works.